# Photo management software (feat. map, calendar, object identification, favorites, screensaver, etc.)

Tags: software, file-management, software-recommendation, photo-management

As much as I have searched online, I can't seem to find a proper **standalone photo management software** that includes the following features:

- A **map** view, where the pictures can be located on a world map, based on their GPS metadata
- A **calendar** view, where the pictures are shown on a calendar, based on the date they were taken (as in their metadata)
- **Object identification** for easier querying (faces, places, any kind of object, etc.)
- **Favorite selection**, where the favorite pictures are pinned/highlighted, and can also be accessed from a separate "folder view"
- Some **screensaver-slideshow** functionality, so that the pictures are shown randomly on the PC/TV.

In the old days, I made use of [Sony's PMB Picture Motion Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Motion_Browser), now discontinued (it featured, among others, a nice calendar for querying pictures). I am also aware that [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) offers some of the above functionality, however, I am looking for a standalone app where my locally stored pictures can be accessed.

The issue I have with the Windows File Explorer is that I need to specifically navigate to a given folder of pictures in order to see its contents, that is, I can't have a global overview of all the pictures I have stored in my computer. I have tried [Adobe Bridge](https://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html), however, I still need to navigate to specific folders with it, and the above functionality is not provided.

What would be the best option for such photo management software?

Comment: Probably will be better to ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check digikam. It has all mentioned functionality and much more. Map and a dates view is there. The pictures can be tagged with custom tags, rated and there is a face recognition engine. With advanced search, you can search according to tags, rating camera parameters etc. Slideshow fucntionality is there, too.